R Reference Class Add New Variable by Name
Consider the following R code :
MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass",
    fields = list(
    ),
    methods = list(
        initialize = function(x){
            #give new attribute x 
        }
    )
)

my_var_name <- 1
obj <- MyClass$new(x = my_var_name)

I would like to add an attribute to MyClass. The name of the attribute is my_var_name, as specified by the user input. The value of the attribute, as will need to be accessed by obj$my_var_name, should be equal to the value of the variable, which in this case is 1. If such a thing is difficult to do in general, I would like it done at least in the constructor. The class of the attribute, which in this case is numeric, can be seen as known.
I know that deparse(substitute()) can be used to extract the variable name. But how do I define an attribute using this ?

If you want dynamically constructed classes then Reference classes are not the right OO system.  To do this with Reference classes define a subclass.
MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass",
    fields = list(),
    methods = list(initialize = function(x) {})
)

MyChild <- setRefClass("MyChild", contains = "MyClass",
   fields = list(a = "numeric"),
   methods = list(initialize = function(x) a <<- 1)
)

obj <- MyChild(1)

obj$a
## [1] 1


Then what is the right system?

I don't think there is an objective answer to that.  The S3 OO system is the most popular and it is highly dynamic.   This defines an object constructor and then creates an object holding a using S3 and then adds another field b to it: MyClass <- function(...) structure(list(...), class = "MyClass");  obj <- MyClass(a = 1); obj$b <- 2
